# Detect tap on a sphere in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch

I want to detect a tap on sphere. I have searched on google and many approaches like ontriggerenter() and using ray cast etc were found.

But what I want to get some values also that where user has touched on ball.

Like if the center of a sphere is x=0, y=0. then I should got positive x and y when user touch upper right corner of sphere.

It is not necessary to get exactly this value, Value can be anything but by these value I should be able to know that user has tapped on one of these 8 portions of ball.

1. upper right near center of circle
2. lower right near center of circle
3. upper left near center of circle
4. lower left near center of circle
5. upper right near corner of circle
6. lower right near corner of circle
7. upper left near corner of circle
8. lower left near corner of circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the methods you found, with raycasting you will get the exact position of the tap. Then you have to transform the centerpoint and the tap position of the sphere to screenspace coordinates. Then you can get the difference between those vectors to get the direction and distance from the center.

PS: Do circles have corners?

you need to have a GameObject with a Collider attatched to it which is set to "Is Trigger". And a script containing following code.

```cs
void OnMouseDown()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    //hits for sure, because we are in the click event
    Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);

    Vector3 hitOnScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(hit.point);
    Vector3 centerOnScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

    Vector3 offset = hitOnScreen - centerOnScreen;

    if(offset.x > 0 && offset.y > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("upper right");
    }else if(offset.x < 0 && offset.y > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("upper left");
    }else if(offset.x > 0 && offset.y < 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("lower right");
    } else //if(offset.x < 0 && offset.y < 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("lower left");
    }
}
```

For the distance to the center it is getting more complicated.
We have to get a vector perpendicular to the from the camera to the center and scale this to the propper size. If we add this to the center and transform it into screenspace we will have the maximum magnitude a point on the surface of the sphere could reach.

```cs
    Vector3 perpendicular = Vector3.Cross(transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position, Vector3.one);
    Vector3 maxDistToCenter = transform.position + (perpendicular.normalized * (transform.lossyScale.x * 0.5f));

    Vector3 maxDistToCenterOnScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(maxDistToCenter);

    float maxDist = (maxDistToCenterOnScreen - centerOnScreen).magnitude;
    float dist = offset.magnitude;

    if (dist < maxDist * 0.5f) // 50% of the way not the area
    {
        Debug.Log("inner 50%");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("outer 50%");
    }
```

Combining both grant you the ability to evaluate any point on the sphere in angle and distance to the center compared with the maximum distance.

If you just want to apply force to the point clicked, you just need a ridgit body and raycasting. This [oficial Unity tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/fun-with-lasers) will explay it.

Maybe you have to combine both answers, but I think the Unity tutorial is sufficient for your needs.

PS: Please ask questwions with the final goal you want to reach and not just  a step you think is needed to get the job done.

Comment: Code will be great help to me as I am not so good with unity, so it will help me to learn fast

Comment: @Yawar Added code. If you need more explanation please let me know.

Comment: @Yawar I added a link to a official unity tutorial you may find usefull.

Comment: I will try this once I am at home. Will give any comments on or mark it as answer. This code will work only on mousedown event or on tapdownevent too ?

Comment: @Yawar aparently it will work for mobile since Unity4

Comment: @Yawar did this help you?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find time to look again into it, I did what you said and superb was it tried just first snippet of code you gave and it worked. And now going for second one

Comment: @Yawar You're wellcome. Please let me know if you still have some problems.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to se raycasts, you can use `"OnMouseDown"`.
Documentation here:                                         http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html
Note: your object needs a collider in order for this to work.

Comment: How can I get the point where the user has tapped? Documentation just said that it will just run when user tapped. Doesn't detect where user has tapped

Comment: Well i dont know if you can retrieve the point in space of where the sphere has been touhed. My sugestion, 1 search for it , 2 you can create "phantom" cubes which indicade the "corners" of that sphere and make then childs of the sphere and reduce the opacity. Then add your touching scripot to them.
Dont know if this suits your problem, maybe you want to click and maybe extrude a vertex. That seems a more complex feature, good luck.

Comment: I am not very good with unity and I think it is a basic functionality. I just want to detect the point on sphere and according to it I will give force to the sphere.

Comment: Hmmm that doesnt sound basic at all, it messes up with math (vectors and angles). If it were a 2D circle i think you would have to calculate the tangent and then a perpendicular vector to that tangent and give it force.
In a 3D world i have no idea. but i think the principle would not be much different. Would recommend you to ask in the r/Unity3D reddit and/or create another question here on Stack.

Comment: You can get the point in space a raycast has hit by RaycastHit.point
@JorgeSantos With raycasting its just a matter of vector calculation.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot didnt know about that, but now lets see. He wants to add force to an object from a single point, isnt this weird?
Because you have a point, not a vector. With a point you have infinite directions in which you can launc the ball. However if you have a vector you can say that the direction that you want the ball to go its the perpendicular vector to your.
Dont know if  im right about this, math is not my strength.

Comment: Everything is 3D but I am making it like 2D. You people call it 2.5D I think.

Comment: So what I am doing is getting that point and adding force on just x and y axis keeping z = 0F